# Why is the cutoff frequency of this Butterworth low pass filter not at -3 dB?

Tags: low-pass

This is a 15th order Butterworth low-pass filter.  I am trying to compare the cutoff frequency in simulation graph with the one I have calculated which is 83.68 Hz.

All I know was the cutoff frequency should around -3 dB but there is no -3 dB point in my simulation graph. Can anyone help to explain this to me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: -3dB with respect to DC. You've neglected the 6dB 'loss' caused by your source and load resistors. It might help if you're looking for 3dB point to use a vertical scale so we can see what's happeniing in the 0 to -20dB area.

Comment: Why do you need to cut high frequencies to less level than -120dB (one millionth)? Can anybody even think of a fraction less than -240dB ( one trillionth)? Won't the filter ring like a bell for ages?

Answer (score 2):

"-3dB" is in comparison to the pass band.

- Measure the output level well below the cutoff - somewhere in that flat area between 1Hz to 70Hz.
- Measure the output level at your calculated cutoff frequency.
- The difference (cutoff level minus passband level) between the two value should be -3dB.